# Cant install Ubuntu 16.10 I/O error Squashfs error

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, squashfs

I was trying to install Ubuntu 16.10 on my pc.
I have already Windows 7 in dual boot installed.
I have all hard disk used by Windows. I had some freed space anyaway (more then 100 gb). I thought that was possible to install Ubuntu on a Windows 7 (I have 2 windows 7 installed in dual boot).
I have launched DVD to install ubuntu. He asked me to dual boot with windows and it has created a partition to make space for the new OS. I have choosen to download every update or programs. And it has installed it correctly.
At the end appears a black screen with a sequence of errors.
Here is a screen shot, a true screen shot :D

[image]

It keep on with that changing the first two numbers and then reboot...
But Ubuntu seems not to be installed, it does not appear in dual boot.
If I try to reinstall, the installer see an Ubuntu OS and ask me if I want to replace it. Anyway it repeats the same errors.
I hope I have explained it clearly, sorry my bad english.
I hope anyone can help me. 
Thank you in advance
^_^
gabriele

Answer (score 1):

Normally squashfs errors like that imply that there are data read errors occurring from the installation media.  So double check that the DVD is free from any scratches or dirt.  The installer also has an early boot option to check the media for errors, so it may be worth double checking with this to see if the media is OK before installing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I have bought a dual dvd, so I try the other side with kubuntu. Thank you again.

Comment: I have exacly same problem with bad sectors on my LiveUSB  - use `sudo badblocks -svfn /dev/sdb1` to check your disk (in my case name was `/dev/sdb1`)